# Shared Sqlite Between Webapplication Projects

Tags: c#, sqlite, ubuntu, asp.net-core

I'm working on TO-DO management solution which has two separate asp.net mvc core web applications and one web api application as;
- Admin panel web app. ( Doing CRUD operations on Todo list )
- Front office web app. ( it will list todo items )
- Webapi web app. ( Also it will list todo items )

How to share one Sqlite db file between those projects ?
I need to give some full path of the Sqlite file in solution so every application should look this path/db. Also I'm using entity framework core, so solution has entity-migrations as well.

I don't want to use MsSql, MySQL, MongoDB etc. Please don't suggest them as a solution. I know "MVC framework Areas" feature. And I know I can host Webapi and Web app on same project but i don't want to combine these projects. Samba share, windows file share is not an option as well. I will use shared hosting as well so I can't use "/var/local/share/app.db" or "D:\app.db" or a temp path etc. So how can I solve this problem?

I'm using Ubuntu OS. Entity freamwork core, All projects uses Asp.net Mvc Core 2.1, C#

Comment: Why do you even want to share the DB between the projects? Since you have WebAPI project, it seems to me that you can simply hide all interactions with the DB behind it, so your Admin panel web app and Front office web app will be hitting different endpoints to access the data.

Comment: Host everything on the same server, have all the programs use the same database file. WAL mode is useful to allow readers at the same time a writer is adding to the database. If you still get lots of lock contention, use a different database engine.

Comment: @StasIvanov It's not a best practice if your all applications on the same network. Why do I need to bother talking with webapi ( there will be a network latency for sure, plus; a constant authentication can slow down the process. Last thing, I will need a load balancer and two web apis because you could lock frontend and backend applications while deploying webapi app. ) So while I can reach the dll(s) and the database in i/o level with direct use, projects talking with the webapi will not my first choice. Backend application should work with db directly.

Comment: @Shawn thank you very much for pointing out the WAL mode. I added retry and retry-count to my all applications because of such kind of errors like lock, but I will definitely check WAL mode too.